# How to fix 403 login post using requests after 3-4 requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Im trying to post login to this site using python requests post. First time i can requests for 3-4 times. But until 5 times i got 403 error from the server.

I already tried to set headers, included referer,origin,user-agent and proxy but not helped much.

```
import json
import requests
response = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/account/login?_k=%2Faccount%2Fsummary'


while True:
        try:
            headers = {
             'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
             'origin': 'https://www.saksfifthavenue.com',
              'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
              'accept-language': 'en-US',
              'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
              'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
             'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'referer': url,
              'authority': 'www.saksfifthavenue.com',
             'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
              'dnt': '1',
            }

            data = {"username":"demo@gmail.com,"password":"Thisisatest"}
            login = response.post(
                'https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/v1/account-service/accounts/sign-in', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)).content
            loginCheck = login.decode()
            print(loginCheck)
            if "Sorry, this does not match our records. Please try again." in loginCheck:
                print('Login failed!!!')
                break
            elif """Your Account""" in loginCheck:
                print('Login success!!!')
            else:
                print('403 Error. Login Failed')
                break
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server detected your spide requests, you request too fast, maybe you can try to set an interval for these requests.

But why you need to login post in a `while`? (and without logout

Comment: I already try to add interval for like 10s for each request. For example i have 10 accounts. I'll make a function to read all the mail/pass from file and then requests with that.

Comment: @Jin Toujou You also can try to logout after a successful login for each account. Just imitate the normal user's behaviour by code.

Comment: The things is i just need to check if the account is valid or invalid. So i think i dont need logout. Because after 3-4 times i request. Its 403

Comment: Why you should logout is that you don't know the logic behind the server side, so all the assumptions is not reliable, and you also using the same `requests.Session()`, that means the cookies in the first response you got would be kept.

Comment: Hm... i already put this in the beginning "response = requests.Session()" thats why i use response.post

Comment: I mean using the same session is wrong here. You can try to put `response = requests.Session()` inside the `while` block...But the more reliable solution is logout, 403 is just a server-side response, it can't explain anything.